# How do I place two divs next to each other without messing up the footer

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here is my HTML, I want to place £first next to £second, but when I try to use float: left;, my footer ignores my content and moves to the top of my page. Is there any way to solve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="lightgrey">
        <header>
            <h1>
                HEADING
            </h1>       
        </header>
        </div id="wrapper">
            <div id="first">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </div>  
            <div id="second">   
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </div>

        </div>
        <footer>
            Footer text here
        </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the CSS. I managed to solve the footer issue by adding display: flex; on the body and flex-direction: column; but now the divs won't sit next to each other

```
body{
        min-height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
}
header{
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: black;
        height: 70px;
        opacity: 80%;
}
footer{
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: black;
        height: 70px;
        opacity: 80%;
        color: white;
        margin-top: auto;
}

}   
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a typo in your div
`</div id="wrapper">` should be `<div id="wrapper">`

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 70px;
  opacity: 80%;
}

footer {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 70px;
  opacity: 80%;
  color: white;
  margin-top: auto;
}

#first {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#second {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="lightgrey">
  <header>
    <h1>
      HEADING
    </h1>
  </header>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="first">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
    <div id="second">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>

  </div>
  <footer>
    Footer text here
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a little change:

```
body{
        min-height: 100vh;

}
```